# angularjs checkboxes show / hide box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkboxlist, ng-show, ng-hide

I have some issues to manage checkboxes and "boxes" containers. The idea is to have a list of checkboxes pre-checked.
Each checkboxes controls a "box" container, and when check / uncheck the checkbox, it shows / hides the containers.

here some codes

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle>Preferences 
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>

        <ul role="menu" uib-dropdown-menu="">
            <li ng-repeat="product in main.products">
                <input class="mycheck" type="checkbox" id="'{{product.id}}'" checked="'{{product.ischeck}}'"> {{product.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the code for the container boxes

```
<div class="col-sm-3 connectPanels" ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-repeat="product in main.products" id="'{{product.id}}Panel'">
    <div class="mybox">
        <div class="mybox-title">
            <h5>{{product.name}}</h5>
            <div ibox-tools></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mybox-content">
            <h2><img ng-src="{{product.images}}" />
                        {{product.type}}
            </h2>
            <p>{{product.description}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried various ways; ng-click, ng-show, ng-hide and ng-change but each time I am block to manage to get the product Id and ischeck values together.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try `ng-show="product.ischeck"` on `<div class="mybox">`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not using ng-model on the input type checkbox element to do the data-binding so that Angular could figure out what is going on.

If you bind the input element to the ng-model directive instead of the checked attribute it works because the ng-model directive does two-way data binding and Angular dirty checks the previous value of the ng-model and updates the DOM respectively if the value has changed.

Check the below code snippet.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);
  
  function DefaultController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.main = {
     products: [
       { id: 1, ischeck: true, name: 'product 1', type: 'product type 1', description: 'product 1 desc', images: '' },
        { id: 2, ischeck: true, name: 'product 2', type: 'product type 2', description: 'product 2 desc', images: '' },
        { id: 3, ischeck: true, name: 'product 3', type: 'product type 3', description: 'product 3 desc', images: '' }
      ]
    };
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle>Preferences 
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>

        <ul role="menu" uib-dropdown-menu="">
          <li ng-repeat="product in ctrl.main.products">
            <input class="mycheck" type="checkbox" id="'{{product.id}}'" ng-model="product.ischeck"/>
            {{product.name}}
          </li>
        </ul>
        
        <div class="col-sm-3 connectPanels" 
        ui-sortable="sortableOptions" 
        ng-repeat="product in ctrl.main.products" id="'{{product.id}}Panel'" ng-show="product.ischeck">
          <div class="mybox">
            <div class="mybox-title">
              <h5>{{product.name}}</h5>
              <div ibox-tools></div>
            </div>
            <div class="mybox-content">
              <h2>
                <img ng-src="{{product.images}}" />
                {{product.type}}
              </h2>
              <p>{{product.description}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am new on angular js. not easy to get all the think at once

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. You can go through the Stack Overflow tour here http://stackoverflow.com/tour to know how Stack Overflow works, you could check this help too http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)